# Disabling keys after enabling them with callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div that slides up (disappears) on keydown. But after the this event I have to disable the keys, otherwise they will continue to scroll to the position of the now "gone" div. I've tried several approaches, like adding and removing active classes, but it didn't work.

Can this work with a callback? Maybe I'm typing it down wrong. Can someone help me out? Thanks. The code:

```js
$("#zero").bind("mousewheel mouseup mousedown", function() { //touchmove
  return false;
});

function start() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow"); //665px
  $("#zero").slideUp();
  $("#nav").fadeIn(1500).delay(9000);
  $('html, body').css({
    overflow: 'auto',
    height: 'auto'
  });
  $("body").on("touchmove", true);
}

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 40 || 13) {
    start(function() {
      // -- -- > CallBack ?
      if (event.keyCode == 40 || 13) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Use `.off()` to unbind the keyup event from document.

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan, it worked :)

Comment: All I did was tidy up your question. I think you meant to send that to @Terry :)